# python library to create python server and client that can also handle data transfer over ports in native python types

Tags: python, server

Is there any python library that allows me to have python server that communicates with python client on a non web port and where arguments as well as results can be passed in native python data type and transformed by library into requisite types needed for transfer protocol

Comment: You could pickle the the objects you want to send and simply use `socket` to get them across?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for Tornado TCP, The data structure can be passed by Json.